# use autofill to increment by 1

Tags: excel

```
=COUNTIF(E$2:K$2,"C")
=COUNTIF(E$3:K$3,"C")
=COUNTIF(E$4:K$4,"C")
=COUNTIF(E$5:K$5,"C")
```

I'm running the above down Column L, but autofill still hasn't learned what I'm doing yet, how can I drag it down to increment each integer by 1?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the $ signs and the the rows will increment

`=COUNTIF(E2:K2,"C")`